# Retrieving elements from a bitshift

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

How would I retrieve "face" from "i"?

```
int i = (id | (face << 16) | (type << 18))
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You already have a reference to face, you can always assign it a new value, not necessarily having to extract it from i.

Comment: Do you know the value range of `id`, `face` and `type` ?

Comment: The reference to i is later lost, as this is a method of compressing a large amount of data.

Comment: Yes, 16 for id, 2 for face, 4 i think for type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, given the restriction that id is only 16 bits wide and that face is only 2 bits wide, use:

```
face = (i >> 16 ) & 3
```

Comment: Thanks! How did you know to mask with 3? (I'm trying to learn this stuff)

Comment: 3 is (in binary) 00000011, so anding X with it can ONLY give you the last 2 bits of X.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't, unless you can guarantee that it's only 2 bits wide, and that `id` is only 16 bits wide, in which case all you have to do is right-shift and mask. Is this a trick question?

Comment: It is in fact only 2 bits wide, and id is 16 bits wide. This is what I originally came up with:
(i >> 16) & 16

But that didn't work!

Comment: @Colby Well you would have to use the *correct* shift and mask. If it's 2 bits wide you need `& 3`.